# ANR из-за TextWatcher-a при вводе текста

Tags: android, ui

При слишком быстром вводе текста в поле ввода получаю следующий ANR:

```
01-30 14:26:46.138: E/ActivityManager(768): ANR in by.example (by.example/.view.EditActivity)
01-30 14:26:46.138: E/ActivityManager(768): PID: 11747
01-30 14:26:46.138: E/ActivityManager(768): Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 41.  Wait queue head age: 13987.8ms.)
01-30 14:26:46.138: E/ActivityManager(768): Load: 8.46 / 8.23 / 7.31
01-30 14:26:46.138: E/ActivityManager(768): CPU usage from 64834ms to 0ms ago (2019-01-30 14:25:37.001 to 2019-01-30 14:26:41.835):
...
```

У меня есть предположение, что это из-за того, что работа `TextWatcher`-а происходит в main (UI) потоке. Потому что виджет для ввода текст реализует интерфейс `TextWatcher` следующим образом:

```
public class EditInfoView extends LinearLayout implements TextWatcher {

   protected MyEditText mValue;
   protected TextView mError;
   ...

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
       // NOTHING
   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
   {
       boolean error = !verifyContent(s) && !StringUtil.isEmpty(s.toString());
       mValue.setStateError(error);
       mError.setVisibility(error ? VISIBLE : GONE);
   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
       if (!text.toString().startsWith("+")) {
           mValue.setText("+");
       }
   }
}
```

И, насколько я понимаю, мне нужно перенести работу методов `onTextChanged()` и `afterTextChanged()` в фоновый поток. Однако я не понимаю, как синхронизировать работу этих методов в фоне с UI, ведь в тот момент, пока будет происходить работа в фоне, данные поля ввода могут изменяться... Буду признательна за любые советы, примеры по этому поводу.